# Debug target in Cordova project Visual Studio 2015 show only start

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I have an Cordova project app in Visual Studio, it was just working fine. Suddenly after installing hyper-v and some other android SDK, I can't deploy or debug in Visual Studio,

The only item I see is start in target menu

Cordova version: 6.3.1

I have tried this

1. Close all VS instances
2. `cd %appdata%\"..\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools"`
3. rename CoreCon folder to something else
4. Launch VS again.

and it didn't work.

I have tried

tools -> option -> tools for apache corcordova -> clear cordova cache

it didn't work.

tools -> option -> tools for apache corcordova -> Run dependency Checker

[image]

I checked all packages in android SDK manager; everything is fine and updated.

Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried disabling Hyper V? From what I remember, it needs to be enabled for Android dev and disabled for Windows.

Comment: I am getting same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to BIOS setting and enable Intel Virtual Technology.
After that you can see multiple debug target options in visual studio.

[image: BISO Setting]